# How to match GTK and KDE themes in Plasma 5

Tags: kde, theme, gtk3, plasma5, gtk2

I would like to set a dark theme that is easy to read (no dark fonts on dark backgrounds or vice versa). And I want a consistent look for Qt and GTK applications (especially Firefox and Libre Office).

I'm running Arch Linux. All packages are very recent.

I know little about themes.

When trying the Breeze Dark and Adwaita Dark themes, the problems I have run into include:

1. text input boxes in Firefox have white text on white backgrounds on many web pages (e.g., google.com).
2. Tooltips (and some menus) in Libre Office have black text on black backgrounds.
3. Menu icons in Libre Office cannot be seen easily due to lack of contrast
4. I have found many webpages are hard to read with a dark GTK theme. (Is this a general problem? I would think not given the popularity of dark themes. I assume I am doing something wrong.)

My general experience with custom themes is a lack of font contrast. Menus, for example, generally become harder to read in many of the themes I tried.

I have heard that there are now three themes that are available for both KDE and GTK: numix, arc and adapta. Are there others?

Which is good in terms of contrast and being easy to read?

Regarding installation, which elements do I need to modify in KDE to achieve a consistent look across all applications? I know I need to change the Plasma 5 desktop theme and the GTK 3 theme. I assume I need to change the GTK 2 theme. How do I know if I need to change icon themes?

Finally, I have a general question. What exactly does a Plasma 5 (or GTK) theme change? What elements are not changed? For example, I know a theme changes colors, but they do not always change all colors (example: white text on white backgrounds in input boxes on google.com indicates a failure to change a color somewhere). I know a theme can change some icons, but again, not all icons are changed. Can anyone give me a simple summary of the rules that come into play here?